# Class Library on Azure VM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to deploy an MVC 5 website to Azure VM, which contains custom domain logic in a separate DLL (C# Class Library).  The application is super simple.. MVC Website calls a single object from the library, which returns a string and displays it in the view.

When I publish the website, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[removed]' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I required to do in order to use a custom DOM in my MVC Applications if I plan on deploying to Azure?  Secondly, will I need to do the same for other 3rd party libraries such as MongoDB, NinJect DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will happen for all the assemblies that are not GAC'ed

You need to

- On Visual Studio, go to your references list
- Select the assembly
- Right click > Properties
- Set the “Copy Local” value to true

Repeat for each assembly that is not GAC'ed and your project depends on, most likely

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?.. I'm quite new to MVC.  How do I do this?